# MySQL: Union of a Left Join with a Right Join

Tags: sql, mysql

Say we have the following tables t1 and t2:

```
t1:
id | column_1
-------------
 1 |   1
 2 |   2

t2:
id | column_2
-------------
 2 |   2
 3 |   3
```

and we want to find the following result:

```
id | column_1 | column_2
------------------------
 1 |  1       | 
 2 |  2       | 2
 3 |          | 3
```

This basically is the union of a right join with a left join. The following code works but feels clumsy:

```
(
    SELECT t1.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2 
    FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
)
UNION
(
    SELECT t2.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2 
    FROM t1 
    RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: here are the tables, if you want to try it:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `column_1` int(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `t1` (`id`, `column_1`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `column_2` int(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `t2` (`id`, `column_2`) VALUES
(2, 2),
(3, 3);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select a.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2
from (
    select id from t1
    union 
    select id from t2
) a
left outer join t1 on a.id = t1.id
left outer join t2 on a.id = t2.id
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer!  I have a more complex example with two keys (test+question) but I was able to adapt your method.  Here is my query. https://sqltest.net/#975330

Comment: Great answer - and can be easily expanded to left joins on multiple CTEs (in addition to two as shown in example). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2 
FROM t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

**Edit:** Doesn't work, MySQL does not know FULL OUTER JOIN.
Have a look here:
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this myself, but this might work:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2, t2a.column_2
FROM t1     
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
RIGHT JOIN t2 AS t2a ON t1.id = t2a.id
```