# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression (ms access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run this code to access however it is giving me this error. I check other sites with related problem and it state that I need to put a parenthesis if there is 2 more joins. I been trying but no luck.

```
         select *
          from 
             (
                select group_id from tbl_group
                union 
                select group_id from table_group\website
             )a
            left outer join  tbl_group  on a.group_id = tbl_group.group_id
            left outer join  table_group\website on a.group_id=table_group\website.group_id;
```

Comment: what is that `a` after `)a` on the 6th row?

Comment: I think it's an alias of the first parenthesis. i derived it from an answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440808/mysql-union-of-a-left-join-with-a-right-join

Comment: @JakeMogra The question you are referring to was for `MySQL`, not `MS Access`, the syntax will not be the same. I suspect the table with a \ in the name would need squared brackets, aliasing tables in access also requires the `As` keyword, and finally outer joins in access also need a few more parenthethis. Please outline exactly what you want to achieve in your instance and we can then help you further.

Comment: I have a schema like this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/212b6/1 I want to display it like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440808/mysql-union-of-a-left-join-with-a-right-join. I also want to find remove the product duplicates (column2 x column3).

Comment: @JakeMogra Please see my answer, it should give an output like that in the question you have linked.

Answer (score 0):

How can you "select tbl_group.group_id from t1" and "select tbl_group.group_id from t2"?  t1 and t2 dont have any reference to tbl_group.  I think you're aliasing your tables all wrong.

Comment: ok. I simplify my code. The half part works runs but stops when I add a  left join

Comment: You're joining on "a.id".  There is no "a.id", because the only thing in table "a" is a field called group_id.

Answer (score 0):

When I compare your code with the link you provided, I don't see where you're pulling t1 and t2 from.

I think it should be tbl.group instead

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*, tbl_group.group_id AS Col1, [table_group\website].group_id AS Col2
FROM ([SELECT group_id FROM tbl_group
UNION
SELECT group_id FROM table_group\website]. AS A LEFT JOIN tbl_group ON A.group_id = tbl_group.group_id) LEFT JOIN [table_group\website] ON A.group_id = [table_group\website].group_id;
```