# mysql INNER/LEFT JOIN with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, union

I have a question regarding the use of UNION ALL and INNER JOIN.
I found some posts regarding this issue, for example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15399/how-to-combine-union-and-inner-join) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440808/mysql-union-of-a-left-join-with-a-right-join) but I did not manage to apply it to my issue.
What I am trying to do is to list 1) the products and 2) the difference between orders and deliveries.
I have 3 table:

- product (id, name)
- orders (id, product, value)
- deliveries (id, product, value)

I managed to get (almost) what I want using the following:

```
    SELECT product
,      sum(total)
FROM (
SELECT product
,      SUM(value) as total
FROM orders
GROUP BY product
union all
SELECT product
,      -1 * SUM(value) as total
FROM deliveries
GROUP BY product)
as alias
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY sum(total) DESC
```

I obtain the following:

- 1    23
- 2    33

When I would like to get:

- computer   23
- car        33

Meaning the product name instead of the product id.
Anyone would have a solution for that? (my INNER JOIN OR LEFT JOIN attempts failed so far)
Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Join in the product table:

```
SELECT p.name, sum(total)
FROM (SELECT o.product, SUM(o.value) as total 
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY o.product
      union all 
      SELECT d.product, -1 * SUM(d.value) as total 
      FROM deliveries  d GROUP BY d.product
     ) od JOIN
     product p
     on od.product = p.id
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY sum(total)  DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. This is exactly what I needed. I must analyse in detail to understand the process. Because I am now trying to add a "WHERE" constraint using the supplier (the table product contains in fact a field "supplier")  and restrain the select to the country of the supplier. Using a simple WHERE p.supplier = 1, I can retrieve the products of supplier 1. But how can I retrieve the products of country 1. I try with INNER JOIN but without success

Comment: @NALL . . . You should ask new questions as question rather than in the comments.  Remember to include sample data and desired results.